# Client Send Raw Data To service WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

WCF service with several methods, log the raw request that came in from the client.

I want to read incoming and outgoing messages.

Client Send Raw Data To service and service can get that data and write it as an XML and we have full control over the XML. That raw data will be write as it is in the body of XML. CAn anybody route me towards any example or sample application that would be really helpful.

I have googled allot but didnt find any example just a one link but that is according to my requirement.

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-read-incoming-and-outgoing.html

Any Help in this regard will be well appreciated because I am stuck here in order to start my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on logging.

The easiest way to do this is to use the WCF Configuration editor. 
Click `Tools->WCF Configuration Editor` this will load the utility, just close the window. 
Then you can right click on your config file and select `Edit WCF Configuration`
Then select `Diagnostics` and turn on everything.

Note: This will have very significant performance implications.

If you have to hand build it (the hard way) then

In your service config in `<system.serviceModel>`

Here is the entry for full logging.

```
 <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
```

you set up the listener as so, change MYPATH to whatever.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\MYPATH.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Thats what I know but my requirement is to send message from client and recive message at server but whatever the client send I get in the body of XML without any added information.